# If statement checking value of ActiveX commandbutton in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run an if statement that checks the value of one of several command buttons on a sheet before proceeding.

Here's a snip of what I'm doing:

```
If Shift_Days.Value = True Then
    Database.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = "Day Shift"
End If
```

Shift_Days is the name of the button. I am getting an Object required error when I try to run this. I have tried several variations of this code, but no luck. Any ideas???

Comment: What's the *value* of a ....button? Do you mean its `Caption`?

Answer (score 0):

Look at Matt's comment. I think you are using the wrong property. You want to user Caption and check it against a string.

```
If Shift_Days.Caption = "True" Then
    Database.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = "Day Shift"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use an ActiveX command button in the excel sheet or maybe just a regular form control button. The way I'm reading the question, it sounds like the psuedocode should sound something like this:

```
'if "Shift_Days" button is pressed (aka button.value = true) then
'    do stuff
'end if
```

With ActiveX controls, you need to reference which spreadsheet it's on. Your code might have to look something like this:

```
If Sheet1.Shift_Days.Value = True Then
    Sheet1.Database.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = "Day Shift"
End If
```

Sheet1 is the default name for Excel Sheets. If you changed the name of the sheet in the Macro's Project View, you'll have to use the new name.

Alternatively, you might just be able to use a Click command to run your code. Don't forget to link the button to your Macro.

```
Private Sub Shift_Days_Click()
    Sheet1.Database.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = "Day Shift"
End Sub
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if this doesn't work.